# Do not run ansible command if file exists

Tags: ansible

I am trying to do a playbook in which I run a command only if a file does not exists. My challenge is that a part of the filename is created randomly. I tried something like:

```
- name: Generate file
  command: <command> "{{ item.name }}"
  chdir: "{{ target_zone_dir }}"
  creates:
    - "{{ target_zone_dir }}/K{{ item.name }}.+[0-9][0-9][0-9]+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].key"
    - "{{ target_zone_dir }}/K{{ item.name }}.+[0-9][0-9][0-9]+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].private"
  check_mode: no
  with_items:
    - "{{ target_zone_domains }}"
```

But my files are alwas generated, even if other one exists.

Comment: how many files are allowed in {{ target_zone_dir }}? If one (or more), just check the content of the dir, it there are more than 0 file, don't create..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What CiroRa said is mostly true, with the difference that it need not be so black-and-white as zero files or else.

```yaml
- command: /bin/ls -1
  args:
    chdir: "{{ target_zone_dir }}"
  register: target_files
- when: not target_files.stdout is search("K"+item.name+".+[0-9]*.(key|private)")
  with_items: "{{ target_zone_domains }}"
```

I'm sure there are more "ansible-y" ways of doing that first task, but you get the idea